# What kind of template engine uses double underscore enclosure?

Tags: html, variables, template-engine, double-underscore

I was asked to continue & modify a CMS project which seems to be custom made. Taken from one of the files is the code below:

```
<!-- BEGINACCESS_DATA=LoginData -->
<ul id="topleftlogin" class="sf-menu">
    <li><a href="__linklogin__">Sign In</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- ENDACCESS_DATA -->
<!-- BEGINACCESS_DATA=LogoutData -->
<ul id="topleftlogin" class="sf-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Hai, __myname__</a></li>
    <li>__panel__</li>
    <li>__logout__</li>
</ul>
<!-- ENDACCESS_DATA -->
```

The above came from an **HTML** file (*form_view.html*).

My question is:

- Are the ones **enclosed in double underscores** (eg. `__myname__`) some kind of *variables*?
- Where do they get their values from?
- What kind of *template engine* uses such format?

I had searched through out the rest of the files but couldn't find the connection between those 'variables' and the data they retrieve. What should I look for??

Comment: What language is the CMS written in?

Comment: The whole CMS contains a combination of HTML, PHP, and JS, it seems. The above code came from an HTML file, though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? What do you plan to do once you find the PHP responsible for the templating?

Comment: I am supposed to modify and add some back-end pages. There are actually a couple of things I don't understand about the whole structure. But I think I'll start with the above first.

Comment: Have you considered that this might be a part of the CMS itself.

Comment: I'm sure it is. But if I were to add something like `Hai, __myname__ from __mycountry__`, for example... I don't know the method to use for the additional variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess some php (regex) script is parsing code between

```
  < !-- BEGINACCESS_DATA--> and < !-- ENDACCESS_DATA -->
```

and replacing tokens like __ % __

Look in php source and in .htaccess

Comment: I had looked but still couldn't figure it out. What should I look for?

Comment: Do html file have any php code (include)?
How you execute form_view.html, directly via www.../form_view.html
or 
www.../somephp?page=form_view.html ?

Comment: form_view.html contains part of the code for the main menu in the header for the whole site. I tracked it and found them in a number of index.php files based on different folders, though not directly.